# How to export excel files using excel-builder.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I have been working on a project with Angular 1 which will require me to build functions to export excel file with some formatting from browser. I found excel-builder.js can be very powerful and useful, but the current tutorial website: http://excelbuilderjs.com/ is not accessible anymore. Can anyone provide me any documentation, especially for excel file formatting?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The data is pulled from back end and based on user filters, so it is dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

you can make excel from html table.As i create a fiddle `here`  http://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/WPpDm/36/

All colors and styles will work inline css. you can custom as you want. I have also user the [Filesaver.js](https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/) to download Blob object.

Comment: Hi Deepak, thank you for your reply. I can not use a html table, since the data is pulled from database and based on user filters, so it is dynamically created. Sorry, I will add this to the question.

Comment: so what kind of data you have ?

Comment: A big json data, but the user can control the filter criteria. Once criteria is set, export the data with excel file with some formatting.

Comment: as excel support only 2 dimensional data, its good practice to export a table. rest you can custom that data. Show a sample..

Comment: The example is using alasql which works fine, but does not provide me with enough excel styling options. http://jsfiddle.net/sudhashri/hyzua2en/

Comment: Show a sample data and what format you want i.e a excel file. then i can design a solution

Comment: I will need two sheets, for each, blue color background for top row and freeze top row, and filter selected for all columns when first opened up. Let me know if this makes sense. Thank you for your help.